# Getting ERROR 419 (unknown status) while uploading image Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel-5.5, image-upload

I am new in laravel and i am trying to integrate pl uploader inside for image uploading.

I am getting unknown status error when i upload image.

Here is the script i am using in view:

```
 var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
        runtimes : 'html5,flash,silverlight,html4',
        browse_button : 'bg_upload', // you can pass an id...
        container: document.getElementById('bg_container'), // ... or DOM Element itself
        url : "{{ url('/') }}/image-upload?_token="+$('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
        unique_names : false,
        max_file_count: 1,
        multi_selection: true,
        flash_swf_url : "{{ URL::asset('admin/js/pluploader/Moxie.swf') }}",
        silverlight_xap_url : "{{ URL::asset('admin/js/pluploader/Moxie.xap') }}",
        filters : {
            max_file_size : '60mb'
        },
        init: {
            FileUploaded: function (up, file) {
                var upload_path = "{{ url('/uploads') }}";
                var img = jQuery('<img alt="click to change image" src="'+upload_path+file.name+'" style="width:auto; max-height:400px;">');
                jQuery("#bg_upload").html(img);
            },
            FilesAdded: function(up, files) {
                jQuery("#progress_file").css("display","block");
                plupload.each(files, function(file) {
                    var img_type = file.name;
                    jQuery("#progress_file").append('<div id="' + file.id + '" >' + img_type + ' (' + plupload.formatSize(file.size) + ')<b></b></div>');
                });
                uploader.start();
            },
            UploadProgress: function(up, file) {
                jQuery("#"+file.id).find("b").html('<span>' + file.percent + "%</span>");
            },
            UploadComplete: function () {
                jQuery("#progress_file").html("");
                jQuery("#progress_file").css("display","none");
            },
            Error: function(up, err) {
                console.log("\nError #" + err.code + ": " + err.message);
                //document.getElementById('console').appendChild(document.createTextNode("\nError #" + err.code + ": " + err.message));
            }
        }
    });
    uploader.init();
```

Here is the route i defined:

```
Route::post('/image-upload', 'ProductsController@upload_image');
```

Here is the `upload_image` function of controller:

```
public function upload_image()
{
    if( ! ini_get('date.timezone') )
    {
        date_default_timezone_set('GMT');
    }
    // Make sure file is not cached (as it happens for example on iOS devices)
    header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
    header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
    header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
    header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
    header("Pragma: no-cache");

    /* 
    // Support CORS
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    // other CORS headers if any...
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
            exit; // finish preflight CORS requests here
    }
    */

    // 5 minutes execution time
    @set_time_limit(5 * 60);

    // Uncomment this one to fake upload time
    // usleep(5000);

    // Settings
    $targetDir = base_path().'/uploads';
    $cleanupTargetDir = true; // Remove old files
    $maxFileAge = 5 * 3600; // Temp file age in seconds

    // Create target dir
    if (!file_exists($targetDir)) {
        @mkdir($targetDir);
    }
    //echo  $targetDir;
    // Get a file name
    if (isset($_REQUEST["name"])) {
            $fileName = $_REQUEST["name"];
    } elseif (!empty($_FILES)) {
            $fileName = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    } else {
            $fileName = uniqid("file_");
    }

    $filePath = $targetDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName;

    // Chunking might be enabled
    $chunk = isset($_REQUEST["chunk"]) ? intval($_REQUEST["chunk"]) : 0;
    $chunks = isset($_REQUEST["chunks"]) ? intval($_REQUEST["chunks"]) : 0;


    // Remove old temp files    
    if ($cleanupTargetDir) {
        if (!is_dir($targetDir) || !$dir = opendir($targetDir)) {
                $data = '{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 100, "message": "Failed to open temp directory."}, "id" : "id"}';
        }

        while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false) {

                $tmpfilePath = $targetDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file;

                // If temp file is current file proceed to the next
                if ($tmpfilePath == "{$filePath}.part") {

                        continue;
                }

                // Remove temp file if it is older than the max age and is not the current file
                if (preg_match('/\.part$/', $file) && (filemtime($tmpfilePath) < time() - $maxFileAge)) {
                        @unlink($tmpfilePath);
                }
        }
        closedir($dir);
    }


    // Open temp file
    if (!$out = @fopen("{$filePath}.part", $chunks ? "ab" : "wb")) {
            $data = '{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 102, "message": "Failed to open output stream."}, "id" : "id"}';
    }
    if (!empty($_FILES)) {
            if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"])) {
                    $data = '{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 103, "message": "Failed to move uploaded file."}, "id" : "id"}';
            }

            // Read binary input stream and append it to temp file
            if (!$in = @fopen($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "rb")) {
                    $data = '{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 101, "message": "Failed to open input stream."}, "id" : "id"}';
            }
    } else {
            if (!$in = @fopen("php://input", "rb")) {
                    $data = '{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 101, "message": "Failed to open input stream."}, "id" : "id"}';
            }
    }

    while ($buff = fread($in, 4096)) {
            fwrite($out, $buff);
    }

    @fclose($out);
    @fclose($in);

    // Check if file has been uploaded
    if (!$chunks || $chunk == $chunks - 1) {
            // Strip the temp .part suffix off
            rename("{$filePath}.part", $filePath);
    }
    $data = '{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "result" : null, "id" : "id"}';
    return response()->json($data);
    //return '{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "result" : null, "id" : "id"}';
}
```

Can anyone tell me where i am wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your url contains`?` ie., a `GET` and you have`POST` routes

Comment: I tried with get as well.. Still getting the same error

Comment: The error is not showing now.. I think this was a cache issue. I don't know what happens and it starts uploading files.

Comment: great post your answer to close it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code starts working. May be it was a cache issue. I don't know what happens and the code starts uploading.

Here is my final code:

Uploader script i am using in view:

```
    var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
        runtimes : 'html5,flash,silverlight,html4',
        browse_button : 'bg_upload', // you can pass an id...
        container: document.getElementById('bg_container'), // ... or DOM Element itself
        url : "{{ url('/') }}/image-upload?_token="+$('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
        unique_names : false,
        max_file_count: 1,
        multi_selection: false,
        flash_swf_url : "{{ URL::asset('admin/js/pluploader/Moxie.swf') }}",
        silverlight_xap_url : "{{ URL::asset('admin/js/pluploader/Moxie.xap') }}",
        filters : {
            max_file_size : '60mb'
        },
        init: {
            FileUploaded: function (up, file) {
                var upload_path = "{{ URL::asset('uploads') }}";
                var img = jQuery('<img alt="click to change image" src="'+upload_path+"/"+file.name+'" style="width:100%;">');
                jQuery("#bg_container").addClass("no-border");
                jQuery("#bg_upload").html(img);
            },
            FilesAdded: function(up, files) {
                jQuery("#progress_file").css("display","block");
                plupload.each(files, function(file) {
                    var img_type = file.name;
                    jQuery("#progress_file").append('<div id="' + file.id + '" >' + img_type + ' (' + plupload.formatSize(file.size) + ')<b></b></div>');
                });
                uploader.start();
            },
            UploadProgress: function(up, file) {
                jQuery("#"+file.id).find("b").html('<span>' + file.percent + "%</span>");
            },
            UploadComplete: function () {
                jQuery("#progress_file").html("");
                jQuery("#progress_file").css("display","none");
            },
            Error: function(up, err) {
                console.log("\nError #" + err.code + ": " + err.message);
                //document.getElementById('console').appendChild(document.createTextNode("\nError #" + err.code + ": " + err.message));
            }
        }
    });
    uploader.init();
```

Here is the route code:

```
  Route::post('/image-upload', 'ProductsController@upload_image');
```

Image upload code in controller:

```
public function upload_image(Request $request)
{
    if( ! ini_get('date.timezone') )
    {
        date_default_timezone_set('GMT');
    }
    // Make sure file is not cached (as it happens for example on iOS devices)
    header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
    header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
    header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
    header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
    header("Pragma: no-cache");

    // 5 minutes execution time
    @set_time_limit(5 * 60);

    // Uncomment this one to fake upload time
    // usleep(5000);

    // Settings
    $targetDir = public_path().'/uploads';
    $cleanupTargetDir = true; // Remove old files
    $maxFileAge = 5 * 3600; // Temp file age in seconds

    // Create target dir
    if (!file_exists($targetDir)) {
        @mkdir($targetDir);
    }
    // Get a file name
    if ($request->input('name')) {
            $fileName = $request->input('name');
    } elseif (!empty($_FILES)) {
            $fileName = $request->image->getClientOriginalName();
    } else {
            $fileName = uniqid("file_");
    }

    $filePath = $targetDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName;

    // Chunking might be enabled
    $chunk = $request->input("chunk") ? intval($request->input("chunk")) : 0;
    $chunks = $request->input("chunks") ? intval($request->input("chunks")) : 0;


    // Remove old temp files    
    if ($cleanupTargetDir) {
        if (!is_dir($targetDir) || !$dir = opendir($targetDir)) {
                $data = '{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 100, "message": "Failed to open temp directory."}, "id" : "id"}';
        }

        while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false) {

                $tmpfilePath = $targetDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file;

                // If temp file is current file proceed to the next
                if ($tmpfilePath == "{$filePath}.part") {

                        continue;
                }

                // Remove temp file if it is older than the max age and is not the current file
                if (preg_match('/\.part$/', $file) && (filemtime($tmpfilePath) < time() - $maxFileAge)) {
                        @unlink($tmpfilePath);
                }
        }
        closedir($dir);
    }


    // Open temp file
    if (!$out = @fopen("{$filePath}.part", $chunks ? "ab" : "wb")) {
            $data = '{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 102, "message": "Failed to open output stream."}, "id" : "id"}';
    }
    if (!empty($_FILES)) {
            if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"])) {
                    $data = '{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 103, "message": "Failed to move uploaded file."}, "id" : "id"}';
            }

            // Read binary input stream and append it to temp file
            if (!$in = @fopen($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "rb")) {
                    $data = '{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 101, "message": "Failed to open input stream."}, "id" : "id"}';
            }
    } else {
            if (!$in = @fopen("php://input", "rb")) {
                    $data = '{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 101, "message": "Failed to open input stream."}, "id" : "id"}';
            }
    }

    while ($buff = fread($in, 4096)) {
            fwrite($out, $buff);
    }

    @fclose($out);
    @fclose($in);

    // Check if file has been uploaded
    if (!$chunks || $chunk == $chunks - 1) {
            // Strip the temp .part suffix off
            rename("{$filePath}.part", $filePath);
    }
    $data = '{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "result" : null, "id" : "id"}';
    return response()->json($data);
}
```